# How to place indicators in seperate columns and left and right controls in bottom of in bootstrap carousel

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

Please consider this code:

```
<div class="container">
    <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
        <!-- Indicators -->
        <ol class="carousel-indicators">
            <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
            <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
            <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
            <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="3"></li>
        </ol>
        <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
            <div class="item active">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-2">
                        <a href="#" class="thumbnail">
                            <img src="Images/1.jpg" alt="Image" /></a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-2">
                        <a href="#" class="thumbnail">
                            <img src="Images/2.jpg" alt="Image" /></a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-2">
                        <a href="#" class="thumbnail">
                            <img src="Images/3.jpg" alt="Image" /></a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-2">
                        <a href="#" class="thumbnail">
                            <img src="Images/4.jpg" alt="Image" /></a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-2">
                        <a href="#" class="thumbnail">
                            <img src="Images/5.jpg" alt="Image" /></a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-2">
                        <a href="#" class="thumbnail">
                            <img src="Images/6.jpg" alt="Image" /></a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="item">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-2">
                        <a href="#" class="thumbnail">
                            <img src="Images/7.jpg" alt="Image" /></a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-2">
                        <a href="#" class="thumbnail">
                            <img src="Images/8.jpg" alt="Image" /></a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-2">
                        <a href="#" class="thumbnail">
                            <img src="Images/9.jpg" alt="Image" /></a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-2">
                        <a href="#" class="thumbnail">
                            <img src="Images/10.jpg" alt="Image" /></a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-2">
                        <a href="#" class="thumbnail">
                            <img src="Images/11.jpg" alt="Image" /></a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-2">
                        <a href="#" class="thumbnail">
                            <img src="Images/12.jpg" alt="Image" /></a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="item">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-2">
                        <a href="#" class="thumbnail">
                            <img src="Images/13.jpg" alt="Image" /></a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-2">
                        <a href="#" class="thumbnail">
                            <img src="Images/14.jpg" alt="Image" /></a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-2">
                        <a href="#" class="thumbnail">
                            <img src="Images/15.jpg" alt="Image" /></a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-2">
                        <a href="#" class="thumbnail">
                            <img src="Images/16.jpg" alt="Image" /></a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-2">
                        <a href="#" class="thumbnail">
                            <img src="Images/17.jpg" alt="Image" /></a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-2">
                        <a href="#" class="thumbnail">
                            <img src="Images/18.jpg" alt="Image" /></a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="item">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-2">
                        <a href="#" class="thumbnail">
                            <img src="Images/19.jpg" alt="Image" /></a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-2">
                        <a href="#" class="thumbnail">
                            <img src="Images/10.jpg" alt="Image" /></a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-2">
                        <a href="#" class="thumbnail">
                            <img src="Images/11.jpg" alt="Image" /></a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-2">
                        <a href="#" class="thumbnail">
                            <img src="Images/12.jpg" alt="Image" /></a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-2">
                        <a href="#" class="thumbnail">
                            <img src="Images/13.jpg" alt="Image" /></a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-2">
                        <a href="#" class="thumbnail">
                            <img src="Images/14.jpg" alt="Image" /></a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
        </a>
        <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
        </a>
</div>
```

and the CSS :

```
.carousel-inner > .item > img,
.carousel-inner > .item > a > img {
    width: 70%;
    margin: auto;
}

.thumbnail img {
    max-width: 100%;
    height: 120px;
}
```

This is the fiddle: [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/28441/)

I want to place left and right arrows in separate columns (but I have 6 item in a row) and indicators in bottom of slider, like this image:

[image]

How I can do this?

Thanks

Comment: Can you provide us a working demo of what you tried?

Comment: @Troyer I provide a DEMO above

Comment: @Arian.. the demo you have provided is not the right one. kindly check.

Comment: @BhavinShah Sorry Sorry, I pasted a wrong URL. Now DEMO is correct

Comment: @Troyer Sorry DEMO URL replaced

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made it playing with positions absolute and % to make it responsive, I comented all the css so you can check why I make those rules :)

**CSS**

```
#myCarousel {
    width: 85%; /* Resize the carousel so it have spaces on left-right for arrows*/
    position: absolute;
    left:  50%; /* forces the carousel be on the middle always */
    transform: translateX(-50%); /* forces the carousel be on the middle always */
    margin-bottom:35px; /* Very important to show the bullets down the carousel and let overflow:hidden show them */
}
.carousel-indicators {
    bottom:-35px; /* Take outsite the arrows*/
    background-color: green; /* color just for show them */
}
.carousel-control .icon-prev, .carousel-control .icon-next, .carousel-control .glyphicon-chevron-left{   
    left: -45%; /* Left arrow absolute position negative to left*/
}
.icon-next, .carousel-control .glyphicon-chevron-right {   
    left: 115% !important; /* Hard override to the right arrow position, without important dosen't works. */
}
```

**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/28448/)**